# Live streaming to VLC through appsrc

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I need to do a live streaming of webcam to VLC through UDP. I have got a good reference from https://gist.github.com/beeender/d539734794606a38d4e3 but i failed to produce the expected output. Video frames are pushed to pipeline using appsrc.

live streaming was displayed successfully with below pipeline:

```
appsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

As i need to live streaming on VLC through UDP, i have updated the pipeline as shown below:

```
appsrc ! videoconvert ! avenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink
```

With the above pipeline i was able to stream video to VLC through UDP, but the video displayed at VLC was having very low quality (Just a blurry video displayed, where no objects can be identified and blocks of green and red are displayed at multiple places). I tried multiple update options and failed to produce the output. Any suggestion will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Please find the code used for pipeline creation.

```
void start_stream(void)
{

  /* Pointer to hold bus address */
  GstBus *bus = nullptr;

  gst_init (nullptr, nullptr);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
  
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");
  appsrc = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "source");
  conv = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "conv");
  
  #if(0)
  /* TEST WITH autovideosink */
  videosink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "videosink");
  #else
  /* TEST WITH udpsink */
  videoenc = gst_element_factory_make ("avenc_mpeg4", "videoenc");
  payloader = gst_element_factory_make ("rtpmp4vpay", "payloader");
  videosink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "videosink");
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(StreamPipeline.videosink), "host", "127.0.0.1", "port", 5000, NULL);
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(StreamPipeline.payloader), "config-interval", 60, NULL);
  #endif

  /* setup */
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "caps",
    gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
    "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB",
    "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1280,
    "height", G_TYPE_INT, 720,
    "pixel-aspect-ratio", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 1, 1,
    "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
    NULL), NULL);

  #if(0)
  /* TEST WITH autovideosink */
  /* WORKING AS EXPECTED, ABLE TO SEE LIVE STREAMING ON DISPLAY */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), appsrc, conv, videosink, NULL);
  gst_element_link_many (appsrc, conv, videosink, NULL);
  #else
  /* TEST WITH udpsink */
  /* NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED, DISPLAYING A BLURRY VIDEO */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), appsrc, conv, videoenc, payloader, videosink, NULL);
  gst_element_link_many (appsrc, conv, videoenc, payloader, videosink, NULL);
  #endif
  
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc),
    "stream-type", 0,
    "is-live", TRUE,
    "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL);
    
   bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
   gst_bus_add_watch (bus, BusWatch, loop);
   gst_object_unref(bus);
 
   gst_element_set_state(StreamPipeline.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
   
   g_main_loop_run(StreamPipeline.loop);
    
   gst_element_set_state(StreamPipeline.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
   gst_object_unref(StreamPipeline.pipeline);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this pipeline and it worked. You can write its C equivalent.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc  ! video/x-raw,format=I420,framerate=5/1,width=1280,height=720 ! x265enc option-string="repeat-headers=yes" speed-preset=5 ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 sync=false
```

in the code below im pulling frames from one pipeline to `appsink`. i use `videotestsrc` and `jpegenc` to simulate you scenario of getting jpeg frames from webcam etc. Then i push that frame to `appsrc` of another pipeline then transmitting it using `udpsink`

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>
#include <thread>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <mutex>

GMainLoop *loopVideoCapture;
GMainLoop *loopVideoStream;

GstElement *Stream_pipeline, *Stream_appsrc, *Stream_conv, *Stream_videosink, *Stream_videoenc, *Stream_mux, *Stream_payloader, *Stream_filter;
GstCaps *convertCaps;

#define AUTO_VIDEO_SINK  0
#define OLD_ALGO         0
#define APPSRC_WIDTH 320
#define APPSRC_HEIGHT 240
#define APPSRC_FRAMERATE 5
std::mutex mtx;

struct FrameData
{
    char* data;
    unsigned int size;
};

FrameData frameData;

void fill_appsrc(const unsigned char *DataPtr, gsize size)
{
    memcpy(frameData.data, DataPtr, size);
}


static void
cb_need_data (GstElement *appsrc,
          guint       unused_size, gpointer    user_data)
{

      static gboolean white = FALSE;
      static GstClockTime timestamp = 0;
      guint size,depth,height,width,step,channels;
      GstFlowReturn ret ;
      IplImage* img;
      guchar *data1;
      GstMapInfo map;
      mtx.lock();

      FrameData *frameData = (FrameData*)user_data;
      size = frameData->size;
      data1 = frameData->data;
      GstBuffer *buffer = NULL;//gst_buffer_new_allocate (NULL, size, NULL);
//
//      g_print("frame_size: %d \n",size);
//      g_print("timestamp: %ld \n",timestamp);


      buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate (NULL, size, NULL);
      gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
      memcpy( (guchar *)map.data, data1,  gst_buffer_get_size( buffer ) );

      GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = timestamp;
      GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, APPSRC_FRAMERATE);

      timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer);
      //gst_app_src_push_buffer ((GstAppSrc *)appsrc, buffer);

      g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
    mtx.unlock();
}

void VideoStream(void)
{
  gst_init (nullptr, nullptr);
  loopVideoStream = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  Stream_pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");
  Stream_appsrc = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "source");
  Stream_conv = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "conv");

  #if(AUTO_VIDEO_SINK == 1)
  Stream_videosink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "videosink");

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (Stream_pipeline), Stream_appsrc, Stream_conv, Stream_videosink, NULL);
  gst_element_link_many (Stream_appsrc, Stream_conv, Stream_videosink, NULL);

  #else

  Stream_videosink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "videosink");
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(Stream_videosink), "host", "127.0.0.1", "port", 5000, NULL);
  Stream_videoenc = gst_element_factory_make ("x265enc", "videoenc");
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (Stream_videoenc), "option-string", "repeat-headers=yes", NULL);
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (Stream_videoenc), "bitrate", 200, NULL);

  #if(OLD_ALGO == 1)
  Stream_payloader = gst_element_factory_make ("rtpmp4vpay", "payloader");
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(Stream_payloader), "config-interval", 60, NULL);

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (Stream_pipeline), Stream_appsrc, Stream_conv, Stream_videoenc, Stream_payloader, Stream_videosink, NULL);
  gst_element_link_many (Stream_appsrc, Stream_conv, Stream_videoenc, Stream_payloader, Stream_videosink, NULL);

  #else

  Stream_filter = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "converter-caps");
  Stream_payloader = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph265pay", "rtp-payloader");

  convertCaps = gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "I420",
    "width", G_TYPE_INT, APPSRC_WIDTH,
    "height", G_TYPE_INT, APPSRC_HEIGHT,
    "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, APPSRC_FRAMERATE, 1,
    NULL);

  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (Stream_filter), "caps", convertCaps, NULL);

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (Stream_pipeline), Stream_appsrc, Stream_conv, Stream_filter,  Stream_videoenc, Stream_payloader, Stream_videosink, NULL);
  gst_element_link_many (Stream_appsrc, Stream_conv, Stream_filter , Stream_videoenc, Stream_payloader, Stream_videosink, NULL);
  #endif

  #endif

  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (Stream_appsrc), "caps",
    gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
      "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB",
      "width", G_TYPE_INT, APPSRC_WIDTH,
      "height", G_TYPE_INT, APPSRC_HEIGHT,
      "pixel-aspect-ratio", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 1, 1,
      "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, APPSRC_FRAMERATE, 1,
      NULL),
    NULL);

  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (Stream_appsrc),
    "stream-type", 0,
    "is-live", TRUE,
    "block", FALSE,
    "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
    NULL);

  g_signal_connect (Stream_appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (cb_need_data), &frameData);


   gst_element_set_state(Stream_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
   g_main_loop_run(loopVideoStream);

   gst_element_set_state(Stream_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
   gst_object_unref(Stream_pipeline);
}

GstFlowReturn NewFrame(GstElement *sink, void *data) {

  GstSample *sample = nullptr;
  GstBuffer *buffer = nullptr;
  GstMapInfo map;
  g_signal_emit_by_name(sink, "pull-sample", &sample);

  if (!sample) {
    g_printerr("Error: Could not obtain sample.\n");
    return GST_FLOW_ERROR;
  }
//  printf("NewFrame\n");

  buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample);
  gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

  mtx.lock();
  fill_appsrc(map.data, map.size);
  mtx.unlock();

  gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);
  gst_sample_unref(sample);

  return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

void VideoCapture(void)
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *videorate, *testsrccaps, *jpegencode, *mjpegcaps, *decodemjpef, *convertmjpeg, *rgbcaps, *convertrgb, *sink;

  gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);

  pipeline     = gst_pipeline_new ("new-pipeline");
  source       = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "source");
  videorate       = gst_element_factory_make("videorate", "video-rate");
  testsrccaps    = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "test-src-caps");
  jpegencode       = gst_element_factory_make("jpegenc", "jpeg-encoder");
  mjpegcaps    = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "mjpegcaps");
  decodemjpef  = gst_element_factory_make("jpegdec", "decodemjpef");
  convertmjpeg = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "convertmjpeg");
  rgbcaps      = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "rgbcaps");
  convertrgb   = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "convertrgb");
  sink         = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "sink");

//  g_object_set(source, "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);

  g_object_set (G_OBJECT(testsrccaps), "caps",
    gst_caps_new_simple (
    "video/x-raw",
      "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
      NULL),
    NULL);

  g_object_set (G_OBJECT(mjpegcaps), "caps",
    gst_caps_new_simple (
      "image/jpeg",
      "width", G_TYPE_INT, APPSRC_WIDTH,
      "height", G_TYPE_INT, APPSRC_HEIGHT,
      "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
      NULL),
    NULL);

  g_object_set (G_OBJECT(rgbcaps), "caps",
    gst_caps_new_simple (
      "video/x-raw",
      "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB",
      "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
      NULL),
    NULL);

  g_object_set(sink, "emit-signals", TRUE, "sync", TRUE, NULL);
  g_signal_connect(sink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(NewFrame), nullptr);

  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN (pipeline), source,testsrccaps, videorate,  mjpegcaps, jpegencode, decodemjpef, convertmjpeg, rgbcaps, convertrgb, sink, NULL);
  if (!gst_element_link_many(source, testsrccaps, videorate, jpegencode, mjpegcaps, decodemjpef, convertmjpeg, rgbcaps, convertrgb, sink, NULL)) {
    g_printerr("Error: Elements could not be linked.\n");
  }


  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  loopVideoCapture = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
  g_main_loop_run(loopVideoCapture);

  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(pipeline);
}

int main(void){

    frameData.size = APPSRC_WIDTH*APPSRC_HEIGHT*4;
    frameData.data = new char[frameData.size];

  std::thread ThreadStreame(VideoStream);
  std::thread ThreadCapture(VideoCapture);

  while(1);
  g_main_loop_quit(loopVideoCapture);
  g_main_loop_quit(loopVideoStream);
  ThreadStreame.join();
  ThreadCapture.join();

  return true;
}
```

to view this udp stream we can use following pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1 port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96" ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! avdec_h265 ! autovideosink
```

to view in VLC:

make a .sdp file for example rtp.sdp
and paste following in it

```
v=0 
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 
s=No Name c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1 
t=0 0 
a=tool:libavformat 56.36.100 
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96 
a=rtpmap:96 H265/90000
```

open this file in vlc ( ctrl+O to open file)
wait for sometime and video will open in VLC

Comment: Hi @hishaamhhh,

Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't worked for me, I am not getting any streaming at VLC (with old pipeline i was getting streaming but its blurry)

I tried using the pipeline you suggested with slight modification as below:

`gst-launch-1.0 appsrc  ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,framerate=30/1,width=1280,height=720 ! videoconvert ! avenc_mpeg4 ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay pt=33 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

Reason for the modifications i made is provided as next comment as i am not able to fit in all information in single comment.

Comment: 1) Caps updated for appsrc:
The video frames injected to appsrc are collected from a callback function connceted to an appsink of another pipeline which looks like below:

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! image/jpeg,framerate=30/1,width=1280,height=720 ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! videoconvert ! appsink`

2) videoconvert is added before avenc_mpeg4: 
  with out this update i was getting issue: "gst_app_src_push_internal: assertion 'GST_IS_APP_SRC (appsrc)' failed Error: Buffer mapping failed."

Comment: @AlamMohd ive added code in the original answer. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your support, but unfortunately thinks are not working for me. To ease the communication, i created a sample setup which demonstrate the issue i am facing. I have uploaded the sample [link](https://github.com/AlamMohd/Sample/blob/main/Sample.cpp)

1) Set AUTO_VIDEO_SINK to 1 -> proper output displayed. 
2) Set AUTO_VIDEO_SINK to 0 & OLD_ALGO to 1 (initial implementing)-> Blurred output at vlc by setting the VLC streaming from udp://@<host>:<port>. 
3) Set AUTO_VIDEO_SINK to 0 & OLD_ALGO to 0 (updated based on your comments)-> output is not displayed at VLC.

Comment: i think you just need to set "block" property to FALSE of "Stream_appsrc". i tried your code on my computer and it worked. use the pipeline i have provided in the answer to get output. run the pipeline first and then run the application

Comment: also its better to wait for appsrc to ask for data then to push buffers into it. use "need-data" callback as i have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: **use the pipeline i have provided in the answer to get output. run the pipeline first and then run the application** -> with this i am able to see output, but not able to stream in VLC by setting VLC streaming from the host address and port. My final goal is to stream it with VLC through UDP. It will be really helpful if you can check whether VLC streaming is working for you. Thanks

Comment: **also its better to wait for appsrc to ask for data then to push buffers into it. use "need-data" callback as i have mentioned in the answer**-> Here the frames are received to callback from appsink, which shall be immediately injected to appsrc (As it is a live streaming). To make these action synchronous, i am not using a callback for appsrc.

Comment: i am able to stream to vlc by modifying your code and using "need-data" callback.i fill the buffer with frame i get from appsink "new-sample" callback and copy that data in the "need-data" callback of appsrc. That lets me stream to vlc

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please share me the update. It will be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: I used your code as it is (but with v4l2src), Its giving me the same blurry video which i used to get if i use the [code](https://github.com/AlamMohd/Sample/blob/main/Sample.cpp) by setting **AUTO_VIDEO_SINK** to **0** and **OLD_ALGO** to **1**. Could you please check the old algo is working fine for you without any update, in that case issue may not with respect to pipeline.

Comment: yes maybe it is because of the decoding as with this code i can properly get the stream via gstreamer pipeline. i ll check what works with vlc

Comment: **with this code i can properly get the stream via gstreamer pipeline** -> I hope this code you meant is old algorithm from GitHub link.
 **i ll check what works with vlc** -> Thanks a lot for your support and patience.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply and thanks for your extended support. Its working :). I have few query. 1) Why is the initial delay before streaming the video. 2) Once i changed the caps property (1280*720 30fps), i am not getting output (i shall further check on this). 3) How does it make a difference setting udp address in VLC network stream option from using sdp file. These points i just mentioned to get your view, its working otherwise. Thanks alot.

Comment: 1.the delay is because in h265 encoding and similar encoding schemes we need a keyframe to decode the whole set of frames from. so we have to wait for the key frame before we can decode.2. the caps need to be consistent in the whole pipeline. 3. sdp can be used for other than rtp/udp sessions too, like rtsp, so in that case we would like set the address.